# AWS Route 53 - Public sub-domain not accessible publicly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have purchased a domain company.com and created a public sub-domain sales.company.com (a public hosted zone in route 53). I mapped(created A record) sub-domain to an internal application load balancer (ALB) i.e. this ALB can only be accessed within my company network. My understanding was a public sub-domain can be mapped to private internal ALB, but when i am trying to access this public sub-domain it is not reachable from internet and i get "This site can’t be reached".
Does ALB has to be a public ALB or is there anything else i need to fix here to make it publicly accessible ?

Comment: Yes, ALB must be public.

Comment: thanks, i will mark it answered if you can post an answer and if you can add why it has to be public would really be great.

Comment: Thanks. Answer provided with extra info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a "public hosted zone in route 53", any A, CNAME or ALIAS record must be made to a **public** endpoint avaialble over the internet. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/AboutHZWorkingWith.html):

> A public hosted zone is a container that holds information about how you want to route traffic **on the internet** for a specific domain.

Thus your ALB must be publicly available. If you want to keep it as an internal ALB (private), you have to create [private hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html). This way you can access it only from within a VPC, not over the internet unless you are using VPN.

Comment: That quoted piece of documentation is a bit misleading. You can absolutely have a private IP address stored in a public hosted zone (or any other DNS server). And your resources in the same network as that private resource will be able to query the public DNS server on the internet to resolve that IP address and then use it to connect to a private resource. I've done this may times with Route53, as well as other DNS servers. The key is that if you want the resource Route53 is pointing to to be accessible publicly, you also need to explicitly make that resource public.