# Internet-facing network load balancer Security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a simple question, If I use an internet-facing NLB wouldn't it be accessible on the internet, by that I mean, the NLB URL can be directly accessible from the internet. How can I restrict that . I don't want my NLB to be accessed from the internet.

My EC2s have SG 0.0.0.0/0 to allow all traffic and EC2s are in private subnets. NLB in public subnet.

Any help please?

Comment: Yes it will be accessible from the Internet. You have to restrict it by restricting the traffic in the target security groups (your EC2 security groups). If you don't want it accessed from the Internet, why did you make it internet-facing?

Comment: The reason it was make internet-facing is because, we have a public hosted zone and which redirects request to NLB. For a public hosted zone we need a internet-facing load balancer isn't int?

Comment: A Route53 public hosted zone doesn't perform redirects, ever. That's not something DNS servers do. You probably mean that it has a CNAME or A record that points to the NLB. That does not need to be an internet-facing NLB in order to create the CNAME or A record that points to it. However, you could also just use a separate Route53 private hosted zone for that record.

Comment: ok, so that means I can still use an internal load balancer for a public-hosted zone? 
I don't need an internet-facing load balancer.

Comment: Yes that's what I said.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69221288/3357735 This contradicts with what you mentioned

Comment: I'll comment on that answer then. I've used private hosted zones to resolve private IPs. It works just fine. It's just a basic DNS server and it works like any other DNS server. Have you not tried it yet to see it if works? It will work fine with an A record pointing to the static IP of the load balancer.

Comment: I just made my ALB internal and when I disconnect from VPN it doesn't take me to the URL . I have All traffic 0.0.0.0/0 added to SG of ALB. Still doesn't work. It works only with internet-facing ALB based on what I tried

Comment: If your load balancer is internal, then you HAVE to be on the VPN to connect to it. It's not clear to me how you think it would work otherwise. Route53 isn't doing any magical network routing to make an internal load balancer accessible on the Internet.

Comment: My previous comment may not be clear. I meant the Record-name under the public-hosted zone only works when I use an internet-facing LB. 
When I point the record name to an Internal LB it says the site can't be reached. I know internal LB cant be accessed from the internet. I am trying to access the record name, not the internal LB URL.

Comment: What happens when you `ping` or `nslookup` the domain name?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want my NLB to be accessed from the internet.

You could have used internal facing NLB for this. But since this is already done, you can allow only people from your org to access it over https & whitelisted IPs.

> My EC2s have SG 0.0.0.0/0 to allow all traffic and EC2s are in private subnets

For EC2, allow all or required traffic only from SG of NLB. This way your NLB gets traffic from internet while EC2 gets only from NLB SG